Set Onedrive "Email notification when others comment on my documents" with Graph
Users can opt out of "Email notification when others comment on my documents" by going to
https://{Tenant}-My.sharepoint.com/personal/{User}/_layouts/15/onedrive.aspx?p=22

And setting "Email notification when others comment on my documents" to off.
I was asked to do it programmatically to all users.
Is there a Graph API to do something like that?
All OneDrive related API documentations speak only about files.
Thanks
